# WCF/webservice architecture question

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a requirement to create a webservice to expose certain items from a CMS as a web service, and I need some suggestions - the structure of the items is as such:

```
item
- field 1
- field 2
- field 3
- field 4
```

So, one would think that the class for this will be:

```
public class MyItem
{
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public List<MyField> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class MyField
{
  public string FieldName { get; set; }
  public string FieldValue { get; set; } //they are always string (except - see below)
}
```

This works for when its always one level deep, but sometimes, one of the fields is actually a point to ANOTHER item (`MyItem`) or multiple `MyItem` (`List<MyItem>`), so I thought I would change the structure of `MyField` as follows, to make `FieldValue` as `object`;

```
public class MyField
{
  public string FieldName { get; set; }
  public object FieldValue { get; set; } //changed to object
}
```

So, now, I can put whatever I want in there. This is great in theory, but how will clients consume this? I suspect that when users make a reference to this web service, they won't know which object is being returned in that field? This seems like a not-so-good design. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: In theory it's great, but you actually won't be able to just make it object. If that works (and I don't remember if it does), at the minimum you will have to put a [KnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) on the class and explicitly list the types that may occur.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the structure of MyField class to have a property of type MyFieldValue which has a simple string property and a list of MyItem (to contain a single MyItem or many) e.g.

```
public class MyField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public MyFieldValue FieldValue { get; set; }
}

public class MyFieldValue
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Or a simpler option might be to add the various options as properties to MyField e.g.

```
public class MyField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue1 { get; set; } // With better property names
    public MyItem FieldValue2 { get; set; } // This property may be redundant as you could just add a single instance to the list below
    public List<MyItem> FieldValue3 { get; set; }
}
```

It would then be up to the consumer to check each property.